# Access mysql database from another system using LAN (Wired or Wireless)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to access a MySQL database from another system using java wireless connection. While changing IP address of both system its not working and thus error occurred as shown below:

> "HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: "Host 'SWAPNIL-PC'
>   is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: So, this is no PostgreSQL question, please retag.   Also, the message clearly states that you have to allow the connection from `SWAPNIL-PC`.

Comment: Firewall problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a MySQL user username@'SWAPNIL-PC' with required privileges

grant select, insert on database_name.table_name to username@'SWAPNIL-PC' indentified by 'secret'

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: [Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-connecting.html) from mysql reference. You should GRANT the user permissions.

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* to 'username'@'SWAPNIL-PC' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

The error message you are seeing is a MySQL error. So, connection to the server is ok. Now, permissions required.